# Uniform convergence of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{kf(x^2)}{1+k^3f(x^2)^2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Let $f:[0,\infty) \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ be a continuous bijection and the series  $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{kf(x^2)}{1+k^3f(x^2)^2}$. Prove that the series converges uniformly on $[\epsilon, \infty)$ when $\epsilon>0$ and not converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$. I tried using M-test for the first part so I suppose to prove $f$ is a increasing function. It seems to be very difficult. Please give me a hand. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if $I, J\subset \Bbb{R}$ are intervals and $f:I\to J$ is a continuous bijection, then $f$ is either increasing or decreasing. For suppose such $f$ is not decreasing, so we may pick $x, y\in I$ so that $x < y$ and $f(x) < f(y)$; and if $f$ is not increasing, we may pick $u, v\in I$ so that $u < v, f(u) > f(v)$. We'll now analyze several cases.

Case $1$: $v < x, f(u) \leq f(x)$. Then we have $f(v) < f(u) \leq f(x)$ with $v < x$, and so there is some $c \in (v, x)$ so that $f(c) = f(u)$ by the intermediate value theorem. And clearly, $c \neq u$, so this contradicts the fact that $f$ is a bijection.

There are three other cases ($v < x$ and $f(u) > f(x)$, $v \geq x$ and $f(y) \geq f(v)$, and finally $v < x$ and $f(y) < f(v)$), and dealing with them is similar.

Thus, your $f$ is increasing or decreasing. And it certainly can't be decreasing, for then the range of $f$ would be bounded above by $f(0)$, and so $f$ cannot have $[0,\infty)$ as its range.

Answer (score 1):

(Note that you might as well replace $f(x^2)$ with $f(x)$, since $x^2$ is also a bijection.)

Any continuous bijection from $[0,\infty)$ to $[0,\infty)$ is increasing. It can't be always decreasing because then nothing in the codomain larger than $f(0)$ would be a value. And it can't be sometimes increasing and sometimes decreasing, because then you could find points $x<y<z$ such that $f(x) < f(y)$ and $f(z) < f(y)$; then the intermediate value theorem tells you that $f$ hits every value between $\max(f(x),f(y)\}$ and $f(z)$ at least twice.

Answer (score 1):

Since the striclty increasing issue has been solved by the other answers, I try to complete the first part of your problem.

Hence for $x\geq \epsilon>0$, you have a uniform bound
$$0\leq \dfrac{kf(x^2)}{1+k^3f(x^2)^2}=\dfrac{k}{\frac{1}{f(x^2)}+k^3f(x^2)}\leq \dfrac{k}{k^3f(x^2)}\leq \dfrac{1}{k^2f(\epsilon^2)}$$
and the series converges uniformly on $[\epsilon,+\infty)$ because $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{k^2}$ is convergent.

As regards $\mathbb{R}$, let us consider the sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that $f(x_n^2)=1/n^{3/2}$ (such sequence exists by bijectivity). If we have uniform convergence also in $\mathbb{R}$ then the series converges to a continuous function $F(x)$. Since $1/n^{3/2}\to 0$ then $F(x_n)$ is bounded. On the other hand, as $n\to +\infty$, 
$$F(x_n)\geq \sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{k/n^{3/2}}{1+k^3/n^3}= \sqrt{n}\cdot \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{k/n}{1+(k/n)^3}\to +\infty$$
because 
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{k/n}{1+(k/n)^3}\to \int_0^1 \dfrac{t dt}{1+t^3}\in \mathbb{R}^+.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. With two above answers, I can do the first part of this problem. How about the second one?

Comment: Oh, your explaination is very nice. Thanks Robert.